# how to view and edit a wordpress php file locally (MAMP)

Tags: wordpress

I am helping out creating a few wordpress templates. I've been sent over the basic content (wp-admin/wp-content/wp-includes folders and other wp-* files).

They've already created a new theme, and one front-page.php file. This file includes "parts" such as get_header and get_footer.

Essentially now they'd like me to create new templates using this theme, and php variables to make updating easier. My question is - how can I view this so I can see what i'm making?

I downloaded MAMP and set up a local server, and if I create a sample .php file in the htdocs folder, that page appears correctly. However when I paste the Wordpress folder that I was sent, nothing loads. Is there a special way to get a front-page.php including partials to load within a theme? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Have you actually installed Wordpress on your local server and activated your custom theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to Install WordPress completely in order to make it work. Then you will be able to add your folder in the "Themes" folder of WordPress..

You can Google "How to Install WordPress on Mamp" for more info... you will find plenty of websites helping you.

I also suggest you read a few blog post on how to create WordPress Themes... :)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for that! I was missing importing database portion of it, it's running now!

Comment: Glad to hear that! If my answer helped you, can you select it as the answer for your post? I would appreciate it :) Have a good one!